# Issues rendering view with flash.now and form_with element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actionview, actionviewhelper

In a Rails 7 controller create action I want to render the `:new` action/view if the model.save action fails.

My initial code looked like this;

```
def create
    new_city = City.new(params.require(:city).permit(:name, :prefecture_id))

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
            if new_city.save
                flash[:success] = "City saved successfully"
                redirect_to city_index_path 
            else
                flash.now[:error] = "Error: City could not be saved"
                render :new, locals: { city: new_city }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This code would render the `:new` action/view and pre-populate the `form_with` element on that page with the values that the user had previously input (stored as the `new_city` object). I also noticed that I can just render `:new` without passing the `locals` parameter and the `form_with` element on that would still be pre-populated page with the values that the user had previously input. Nice.

```
else
    flash.now[:error] = "Error: City could not be saved"
    render :new
end
```

The `flash.now[:error]` message would not render, though. I found a fix on [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29036)  which works for rendering the `flash.now` message.

```
else
    flash.now[:error] = "Error: City could not be saved"
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity               
end
```

When I do this, however, the `:new` view renders but the `form_with` element is not pre-populated with the user input values. If I try to also pass in `locals` then the `status` stops working (therefore no flash message).

Is there a way that I can pass the status (so that the flash message works) and also the `new_city` model (so that if the `new_city.save` action fails then the form will re-render displaying the data that the user had previously input)?

Comment: Can you add your layout code?

Comment: my guess is that new_city is not an environment variable, then it can't be used in the view. You can change your variable `new_city` to `@new_city` also you have to make sure your :new view is using this environment variable in the form.

Comment: Great ! (Although I meant instance variable, not environment variable)